# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' after pip install -- following TF official install docs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have recently installed TensorFlow using the pip install instructions on the TensorFlow official website. Due to technical issues, I downgraded to Python version 3.6.2. However, when I entered IDLE, opened an additional file and entered:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Python responded with the message:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gg-mac/Documents/firsttensorflow.py", line 1, in  <module>
 import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
>>>
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue? I am simply trying to know where to run Tensorflow, as it is not specified anywhere on the website. I am developing an audio recognition program, if that is relevant. Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Sincerely,
Suren Grigorian

Comment: What happens if you do a case-insensitive search on the entire file system for 'tensorflow' ?   This will answer the questions "Is anything there at all?" and "What seems to be installed?"  Consider appending this list, with your environment configuration, to the question.  It may help someone to help you further.  After that, consider whether these paths will be found by the version of python you are running.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to diagnose without more information, since we cannot test the absence of it. Perhaps try this:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

and try again, or perhaps run

```
python3 /Users/gg-mac/Documents/firsttensorflow.py
```

from the Terminal (looks like you're running Mac OS).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. When I ran it in the Terminal, it gave no error message.

Comment: @SurenGrigorian Question answered?